# Value equality of c_str == string vs c_str == c_str

Tags: c++, string, equality, libpqxx, c-str

I'm trying to compare libpqxx [`c_str`](http://pqxx.org/devprojects/libpqxx/doc/2.6.8/html/Reference/a00256.html#8123fd1430eb4cfaa1f5095b44ceae86) values.

If I try to compare them directly, `result1[0][0].c_str() == result2[0][0].c_str()`, for example, they do not `return true` when they have the same string values.  The only way to compare them properly is to use `strcmp`.

However, if I'm comparing a libpqxx `c_str` to a `std::string` with `strcmp`, the compiler complains that an argument of `strcmp` cannot be a `std::string`, yet most strangely of all to me: if I compare something like `result1[0][0].c_str() == some_std_string`, the comparison will `return true` if they possess the same value, `false` otherwise.

Why is this?  Is this something particular to libpqxx?  If not, is this standard behavior?

Comment: `result1[0][0].c_str() == result2[0][0].c_str()` Well yeah, those are two different pointers.

Comment: @Gracchus, it's worth noting that even if `string` didn't have an `operator==` for char pointers, the mere fact that a `const char*` can be implicitly made into a `string` means that it would work anyways. Seeing that no `operator==` exists, the compiler would look for a way to implicitly convert the `const char*` into a `string`, would find the non-`explicit` string constructor that accepts a single `const char*`, and use it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It happens because `std::string` is a class, while `const char*` (the type returned by `c_str`) is, well, a pointer type. Comparing pointers returns `true` if the pointers point to the same memory location. Classes, on the other hand, can define what equality means to them.

Since `string`s and `const char*` are fairly analogous, the `string` class defines a method of comparing string objects to `const char*` pointers. It also defines how to convert a `char` pointer into a string. However, this is essentially a one-way street, as it does not define how to create a `const char*` from a string using mere operators or implicit conversions. This is why you can't use `strcmp` on them.

`Strcmp` is a function from the C standard library. C has no classes and types cannot define basic behavior like C++ classes can. Therefore, C defines a bunch of function to deal with char pointers, and char pointers only.

This kind of inconsistency between char pointers and strings isn't limited to equality. For instance, `std::string` supports concatenation with the `+` operator: this means that `string + string` works, `const char* + string` works, `string + const char*` works, but `const char* + const char*` results in a compile-time error, because pointers don't define this kind of operation.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `c_str()`, too!

```
if (strcmp(result1[0][0].c_str(), some_std_string.c_str()) == 0)
{
    ...
```

or use `operator ==` of `std::string`

```
if (result1[0][0].c_str() == some_std_string)
```

Comment: Thank you for giving me a aesthetically consistent method!

Comment: @Gracchus plz choose my answer if it helps you >o< Btw, Doesn't `string` of lipqxx support `operator ==`? How bad...

Comment: you should at least add some words about the implicit cast (via ctr) in the second case

Comment: implicit cast? where??

Comment: Do you mean... result1[0][0].c_str() will be implicit-cast? No, `std::string` has not only `bool operator ==(const std::string&, const std::string&)`, but also `bool operator ==(const char*, const std::string&)` and `bool operator ==(const std::string&, const char*)`